# NFC - How to check if device still has contact to chip

Tags: android, nfc

I'm using a nfc chip to open an app. Now when the device still has contact to the nfc chip and I press the home button I want to reopen the app. How can I manually check the contact?

Comment: Check when your apps onStop() or onPause() is called, then launch a service that will reopen your app. Though, you should never 'lock' your users inside your app.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can't. The Home button is handled by the Android OS. So unless you want to modify your Android OS, this is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to use a thread which checks the contact and whether the app is in background?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the NFC API, but maybe you could use a Service to check the NFC card in the background. But this will probably drain your battery fast.